# O thread de chamada não pode acessar este objeto porque ele pertence a um thread diferente

Tags: c#, wpf

Segue o código:

```
private async void button_1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{    
    var listenPort = 11000;
    var listener = new TcpSocketListener();
    listener.ConnectionReceived += async (senders, args) =>
    {
        var client = args.SocketClient;
        var reader = new StreamReader(client.ReadStream);
        var data = await reader.ReadLineAsync() + "\n";

        var split = data.Split('#');

        button_proximo.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.ClickEvent));

        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
        await client.WriteStream.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        await client.WriteStream.FlushAsync();
    };

    await listener.StartListeningAsync(listenPort);
}
```

O erro que recebo:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'O thread de chamada não pode
>   acessar este objeto porque ele pertence a um thread diferente.'

Esse erro acontece só dentro `ConnectionReceived`, se eu colocar a linha `button_proximo.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.ClickEvent));` fora do `ConnectionReceived` funciona normal.

Alguma solução ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Voce tem que aceder aos componentes da interface na mesma thread onde eles foram criados (também conhecido pela thread da UI). Para fazer isso voce pode [usar o dispatcher](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1644079). Exemplo:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
  DispatcherPriority.Background,
  new Action(() => 
    button_proximo.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.ClickEvent));
);
```